# 2 joins in one query with parentID

Tags: mysql, join

I have the two following database tables:

News Table:

```
newsID, topic, categoryID
```

Category Table:

```
categoryID, title, parentID
```

I want to get the newsID, the topic, the title of the main category and only IF parentID is NOT 0, the title of the parent category.
Currently im stuck like that:

```
SELECT news.newsID, news.topic, category.title
FROM news
LEFT JOIN category
ON news.categoryID = category.categoryID
WHERE news.newsID = 1
```

I'm still missing the parent title if available. What's the most performanced way to get it (if available)?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see `categoryID` in the `news` table?

Comment: you don't have `categoryID` column listed in your psudo-DDL for the `news` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `categoryID` column in the `news` table AND that the `category` table is a self-referencing hierarchy, meaning that a child's `parentID` references the `categoryID` column of the parent row in the same table:

```
SELECT          n.newsID, n.topic, c.title, p.title as parentTitle
FROM        news n
LEFT JOIN   category c
ON         n.categoryID = c.categoryID
LEFT JOIN   category p
ON     c.parentID = p.categoryID
WHERE       n.newsID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a `categoryID` column on the `news` table:

```
SELECT n.newsID, n.topic, c.title, cp.title as parenttitle
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN category c ON n.categoryID = c.categoryID
LEFT JOIN category cp ON cp.categoryID = c.parentID
WHERE n.newsID = 1
```

Comment: +1:  i would only alias the `cp.title` out column with a different name for clarity